# How to sort JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do I sort an array containing JSON content based on the number of keys in each object in ascending order?

Program in JavaScript

#### Input:

```
[{a : 'a', b : 'b'}, {a : 'a'}, {a : 'a', b : 'b', c : 'c'}]
```

#### Output:

```
[{a : 'a'}, {a : 'a', b : 'b'}, {a : 'a', b : 'b', c : 'c'}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! PLease see [ask] and [mcve]. Always, add the attempts.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: `input.sort(function(a,b){
return Object.keys(a).length-Object.keys(b).length;
})`

Comment: you can't sort JSON, as JSON is a string .. you need to parse it first to a javascript Object, then you can sort the object using Array#sort

Comment: I tried extracting counts of each json but could not sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort it by the Object's keys length:

```
var arr = [{a : 'a', b : 'b'}, {a : 'a'}, {a : 'a', b : 'b', c : 'c'}];
var res = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return Object.keys(a).length - Object.keys(b).length;
});
```

Comment: Its correct Thank you.